# HTML Textarea text to XML

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, xml-parsing

I have a HTML Textarea in which the list appears like this :

jack=rider

steven=conrad

nancy=gagan

I have to create a button, which once pressed it should show the text in XML any way, In a file or in the same textbox.

```
<list1>jack=rider</list1>

<list2>steven=conrad</list2>
```

and so on.

The coding has to in javascript. Please help.

Comment: Hey, welcome to stackoverflow, we can help you make your program work, but you have to provide us with some code to start with. We cannot do the entire job for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get completely this question, by the way if your aim was to turn a HTML document object, and whatever contents it has in XML, this is pretty straightforward if you have the right tools. We are using [Wicked Google Xpath](https://github.com/google/wicked-good-xpath) here, a pure JS implementation of the DOM Level 3 XPath specification.

So let's see how it works here, this can help you to build your contents from HTML code, but again, I'm not sure if this was your objective:

```js
var console = {
  log: function(s) {
    document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += s + "<br/>"
  }
}
console.log("XML:installing parser...");
wgxpath.install(window)
console.log("XML:Parser installed.");

console.log("XML:Evaluating XPath...");

var expression = window.document.createExpression('//*[@id="contents"]');
console.log("XML:Evaluating XPath text");

var result = expression.evaluate(document,
  XPathResult.STRING_TYPE);
console.log("XML:Contents <br><br>" + result.stringValue);

console.log("<br><br>XML:DONE.");

var expressionXML = window.document.createExpression('//*[@id="contents"]/node()');
console.log("XML:Evaluating XPath node()");

var resultXML = expression.evaluate(document,
  XPathResult.ANY_TYPE);
console.log("XML:Contents <br><br>" + resultXML.iterateNext().textContent);

console.log("<br><br>XML:DONE.");
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/google/wicked-good-xpath/releases/download/1.3.0/wgxpath.install.js"></script>
<div id="console" />
<div id="contents" style="display:none;"><textarea rows="4" cols="50">
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies. 
</textarea>
</div>
```